# Openbts installation error due to liba53

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

i tried running sudo ./build.sh B200 openbts and this is the output i got

```
sudo ./build.sh B200 openbts
checking for a supported radio type
- found
single component specified
- found, building openbts
checking for a compatible build host
- fully supported host detected: Ubuntu 16.04
adding additional repo tools
- done

checking build dependencies
- done

make a home for this build
mkdir -p BUILDS/2019-07-02--11-35-10
openbts - building Debian package
cd openbts
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package openbts
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 5.0
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Range Packager <buildmanager@rangenetworks.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
dpkg-source --before-build openbts
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: liba53
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
ERROR: command failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search turned up this:

That does not look like OpenBTS 2.8. The library that it is complaining about (a53) was not introduced until 3.1. The source for liba53 can be found here:
 - https://github.com/RangeNetworks/liba53

After cloning that repo, execute the following:

```
$ cd liba53
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Re-running the compilation on your OpenBTS source should then succeed.

From the openbts mailing list [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/openbts/mailman/message/32346584/)

Comment: after running ./configure, this is what i got
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Then just try make.  There's not configure.ac in the repo.  It builds fine here without the configure step

Comment: done. and i got 
cp liba53.so.1.0 /usr/lib
cp -P liba53.so.1 /usr/lib
cp -P liba53.so /usr/lib
cp a53.h /usr/include
but then the code still wont compile due to liba53 being an unmet dependency

Comment: And you did the sudo make install?

Comment: yes. here is the output
tcsbts19@tcsbts19-oneTwo-M3700:~/dev/liba53$ sudo make install
cp liba53.so.1.0 /usr/lib
cp -P liba53.so.1 /usr/lib
cp -P liba53.so /usr/lib
cp a53.h /usr/include

Comment: Then it should be working and you should ask on github or the mailing list.